# Заставить $.get ждать появления элемента

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Как получить содержимое страницы по ссылке, если страница некоторое время после открытия ждет появления данных с ajax-запроса и крутит анимацию загрузки? Нужно как-то заставить $.get ждать, пока анимация не станет hidden, но как?

Comment: а зачем аяксу ждать анимацию загрузки? зачем такое поведение?

Comment: Чтобы вместо белого листа была анимация загрузки.

Comment: ну. ещё раз спрошу: зачем **аяксу** ждать, анимацию? это анимация должна реагировать на аякс и его состояния, а не наоборот

Comment: Пусть реагирует, как ей вздумается. Мне нужны только данные, которые появляются после ее исчезновения.

Answer (score 0):

Суть проста:

- Перед отправкой `ajax` запроса - показываем анимацию загрузки
- При `success` - убираем анимацию загрузки и вставляем данные (отображаем данные).

В методе **[$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)** есть даже вспомогательный `callback` под названием `beforeSend`, где можно как раз показать анимацию. Ну а у `$.get` только перед ним самим

Comment: На какой вопрос этот ответ?

Comment: @Роман Тут решение проблемы улаживания отображения/убирания анимации до и после получения данных. Ровно то, что вам нужно

Comment: Мне нужен html код страницы, загруженной по ссылке, а не анимация.

Comment: @Роман тут нет ответа про то, как получить анимацию. А страницу вы итак получается через ajax. Вам стоит чётче сформулировать свою проблему

Comment: Четче некуда. Вызываю $.get, он открывает ссылку, ждет, пока там появятся данные, берет html и отдает мне. Вы отвечаете на свой вопрос, а мой даже не читали.

Comment: @Роман phantomJs в помощь